# Rectangle Class and Templates C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a code that creates a rectangle class and also create two classes which compare the perimeter and the area of two rectangles and return the larger of the two. I keep getting errors that there is an expected ';' in places which I don't think they belong. Any suggestions?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename Object, typename Comparator>
const Object & findMax( const vector<Object> & arr, Comparator isLessThan )
{
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for( int i = 1; i < arr.size(); ++i )
      if( isLessThan( arr[ maxIndex], arr[ i ] ) )
          maxIndex = i;

  return arr[ maxIndex ];
}

class AreaComparator
{
  public: 
    int compare( Rectangle lhs, Rectangle rhs ) const
  { return double.compare( lhs.getArea(), rhs.getArea() ); }
};

class PeriComparator
{
  public:
    int compare( Rectangle lhs, Rectangle rhs ) const
  { return double.compare( lhs.getPerimeter(), rhs.getPerimeter() ); }
};
class Rectangle
{
  double length, width;

  public:
    Rectangle( double l, double w) 
  {
        l = length;
        w = width;
  }
    double getArea()
  {
        return length * width;
  }
    double getPerimeter()
  {
        return ( 2 * length) + ( 2 * width );
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout <<(findMax(new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(1, 5), new Rectangle(2,    3) }, new AreaComparator())) << endl;
cout <<(findMax(new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(1, 5), new Rectangle(2, 3) }, new PeriComparator())) << endl;

system("PAUSE");
delete Rectangle[];
delete AreaComparator[];
delete PeriComparator[];
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: Live example [here](http://ideone.com/Kp54xt), looks like you need to prototype `Rectangle` Among other things ... lots of other things

Comment: The `delete` statements are completely bogus, for a start.

Comment: Also `double.compare` is not c++, are you coming from c#? maybe you mean `compare<double>(...`

Comment: Off the top: you are passing `AreaComparator*` pointer to `findMax`. The function tries to effectively do `AreaComparator* isLessThan; isLessThan(something, somethingElse);` which is of course nonsense.

Comment: You are passing `Rectangle*` to `findMax`, which expects `std::vector<Something>` instead.

Comment: You need to assign your `new` objects to variables that you can manipulate and later dispose. Or else you could simply declare them as local scalars within `main()`;

Comment: Lots of memory leaks! C++ is not C#

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

Building on @Logicrat's comment, I would suggest assigning all your new objects to local variable names, and then splitting up your `cout` statements into shorter pieces (multiple short `cout`'s replacing each long `cout`).  If the `;` problem persists, you will more easily see why.